# how to make qooxdoo effects work?

Tags: effects, qooxdoo

I'm trying figure out how to make something like this work:

```js
qx.Class.define("effects.Application",
{
extend : qx.application.Standalone,
members :
{
main : function()
{
    // Call super class
    this.base(arguments);

    // Enable logging in debug variant
    if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug"))
    {
        // support native logging capabilities, e.g. Firebug for Firefox
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        // support additional cross-browser console. Press F7 to toggle visibility
        qx.log.appender.Console;
    }

    var button = new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button");
    var fadeToggle = new qx.fx.effect.core.Fade(button.getContainerElement().getDomElement());
    fadeToggle.set({
       from : 1.0,
       to : 0.0
    });

    var doc = this.getRoot();
    doc.add(button);

    button.addListener("execute", function() {
        fadeToggle.start();
    },this);
}
}
});
```

This is the entire Application.js
Just trying to do an effect on something without luck.. It's like qooxdoo is ignoring the effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the DOM element. As you execute

```js
button.getContainerElement().getDomElement()
```

it has not yet appeared in the DOM tree. So the return value of the function is `null`. Qooxdoo has a rendering queue, so the manifestation of what you do in the program is mostly delayed a bit. Use the 'appear' event to work around this:

```js
var button = new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button").set({
    enabled: false
});
var doc = this.getRoot();
button.addListener('appear',function(){
    var fadeToggle = new qx.fx.effect.core.Fade(
        button.getContainerElement().getDomElement()
    ).set({
        from : 1.0,
        to : 0.0
    });
    button.addListener('execute',function(){
        fadeToggle.start();
    });
    button.setEnabled(true);  
});
```

The bit with disabling and enabling the button is just to show off ... it will be so fast that no one will notice.

There are also several *.flush() methods in the framework where you can force the rendering to happen immediately, so calling them (the right ones :-)) might also be an option ... but since JS should be written asynchronously whenever possible, the above is probably the right thing todo.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to look at

- the corresponding [manual page](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.4.x/pages/low_level/qooxdoo_animation.html)
- the code of the animation demos, e.g. [this](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.4.x/demobrowser/index.html#animation~Transition_Color.html) (although I concede they mostly hoook the animation to user actions)